# Remove certain attributes for content before hitting wp-json

Tags: php, theme-development

I want to remove the `data-id` attribute from the linkChecker component but, it seems like even when it is removed the data being posted to wp-json still maintains the `data-id` attribute.

I understand the value of the data-id field but, unfortunately, with that field in the API POST it responds with a 401 error whenever it detects an ID in the content field.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.